# Why can I not see Java applets in Firefox 8 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, java

Examples are the Java "Play Against The Computer" applet on a chess website; there is also the Java chat room on another website that just shows a white area where the chat room was supposed to be.

I do have the Java plugin for the browser, icedtea6-plugin, installed, because Synaptic Package Manager shows a green square next to it. Also, when I follow the link http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icedtea6-plugin, I get an alert box that says that the icedtea6-plugin is already installed.

I also have Java installed, because I can run Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Having Java installed on your computer is not quite the same thing as having a Java browser plugin installed. I would suggest taking a look at the [Icedtea Java Plugin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icedtea6-plugin)[image: Icedtea Java Plugin] and see if that fixes the problem; either click the link to install or run `sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin` in a terminal.

.....

Note that you may have to restart Firefox for it to recognize the plugin.

Comment: Thank you. But I notice that icedtea6-plugin is installed. Perhaps it is not compatible with Firefox 8.

Comment: I corrected the URL to the icedtea6-plugin. The "6" was missing. The edit must still be peer reviewed.